# How does one use Tensor.cpu() to copy a tensor to host memory?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm looking at the AI Feynman logistic regression code using David Shapiro's https://colab.research.google.com/github/dcshapiro/AI-Feynman/blob/master/AI_Feynman_2_0.ipynb#scrollTo=I6GEtqkYYwfF.

After training the NN for a while it throws the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    755             return handle_torch_function(Tensor.__array__, (self,), self, dtype=dtype)
    756         if dtype is None:
--> 757             return self.numpy()
    758         else:
    759             return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)

TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

Looking at some of the answers to this problem, I've changed the `self.numpy()` in the above code to:

1. `self.cpu().numpy()`
2. `self.detach().cpu().numpy`
3. `cpu().self.numpy()`
4. `self = self.to('cpu') ...`
5. `self.to('cpu').numpy()`

...none of which work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In Colab, switch off the GPU. Run it only on CPU and the problem doesn't arise.